# In Foundation Zurb, how do I make a class only effective on certain screen sizes?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a button that has the `right` class so it aligns to the right when on the desktop view of the page but when the page is in mobile view, I want to disable the `right` class from it and make it centered. How do I do this in Foundation?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 column">
            <div class="panel">
                <h4>Get in touch!</h4>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-9 column">
                        <p>We'd love to hear from you!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-3 column">
                        <a href="#" class="radius button right">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The element I want centered when in the mobile view is the `Contact Us` button.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on the zurb-foundation, but the @media css is one way responsive pages are handled.
This should help.
   [w3c page on @media](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries4/)

I noticed the code after the post and without the css it is hard to know what needs to be changed but putting the @media at the end of the css is what you need to do.

something like this.

```
#top{height:auto;border:double #ccc;height:150px;width:60%;margin:10px auto; }
#center_collum{ border:solid px;min-height:650px;width:57.0%;margin:0% auto;padding-  left:1em;}

@media screen and (min-width:1600px){
body{font-size:100%; }
#top{width:40% }

 }
 @media screen and (max-width:1600px){
body{font-size:100%; }
#top{width:50% }
#center_collum{width:56%; }
 }
@media screen and (max-width:960px){
body{font-size:60%; }
#top{width:70% }
#center_collum{width:54%; }
}
 @media screen and (max-width:440px){
body{font-size:50%; }
#top{width:100% }
#center_collum{width:50%; }
hr{margin-top:1.8em;width:100%}
}
```

The above is just a example of the way it works from a piece of css I am using.
It works on the screen size of the monitor, what you want is something like this.

```
  @media (device-some_attribute_value)
```

The link explains how it all works.

If you want to actually change the class it would be done with JavaScript

```
element.setAttribute("class","new_class")
```